# My encryption code can't find a file "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file"

Tags: python, cryptography, zip

So I'm currently working on a project where I should be able to select a folder, encrypt everything inside that folder and put it into a .zip file.

The code where I encrypt the files and put them into the .zip file is this one:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(path,'w') as my_zip3:
        for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directoryname):
            for filename in filenames:
                print(filename)
                self.encrypt(filename,key)
                my_zip3.write(os.path.join(folderName, filename))
```

Now, the problem is that when I ONLY use the "print(filename)" part, it prints all the files correctly, but when I add the other 2 lines of code to encrypt and add the files to the zip, it just gives me this error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file"
I also have other parts of the code that WORK where I do the same without the encrypting part.
Here's the encrypt function:

```
def encrypt(self, filename, key):

    f = Fernet(key)

    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        file_data = file.read()

    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)

    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        file.write(encrypted_data)
```

Comment: Huh, why are you showing the code that work? Show the `self.encrypt` function, everything you said paints the problem inside that function

Comment: Added it to the question, thanks

Comment: writing an encrypted copy of the file over the original looks like it's going to lead to problems!  I'd suggest writing to a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` and then using the `arcname` parameter of `zipfile.write` to give the file the "right" name in the archive.  or just use `zipfile.writestr(filename, encrypted_data)`

Comment: True. I'll keep it in mind. It certainly can lead to problems easily if the key is lost and you lose all the original files. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the error gets thrown in the line *with open(filename, "rb") as file:* within the encryption.
With filename, you only get the name of the file, not the path to it. Since you're walking through a directory, you could be anywhere inside that structure, so the is not found.
Try concatinating the directory path as you did with os.path.join(folderName, filename).

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it already. I changed "self.encrypt(filename, key)" with  "self.encrypt(os.path.join(folderName,filename),key)"